# XCTAssert NSSet count

Tags: ios, unit-testing, xctest

I'm trying to write unit tests with XCTAssert.
I have a NSSet and I want to test if this set holds any objects.

I check with:

```
XCTAssertTrue((mySet.count == 0), @"mySet should not be empty");
```

The test always passes. In my testcase the NSSet is empty. When i insert a if-statement and ask for `if (mySet.count == 0)` it is true - so they are no elements in the NSSet.

Why is the assert not breaking?
Or: How do I check if a NSSet or NSArray is empty with XCTAssert?

Comment: How are you creating the set and should it be empty at that point? The string you pass in is contradicting the actual tests.

Comment: The NSSet is a relationship from a NSManagedObject. I want to let the test fail when the NSSet is empty. So the NSSet should always hold data. When count is 0 --> break with an error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The format for the function is

```
XCTAssertTrue( <some condition>, @"Some string that gets printed to the console if the test fails" )
```

The test passes if *some condition* evaluates to true, and fails if false. Example:

```
// create empty set
NSSet *mySet = [[NSSet alloc] init];
// this test passes because the set is empty
XCTAssertTrue( [mySet count] == 0, @"Set should be empty" );

// Set with three items
NSSet *setTwo = [[NSSet alloc] initWithArray:@[ @"1", @"2", @"3" ]];
// passes test because there are three items
XCTAssertTrue( [setTwo count] == 3, @"We should have three items" );
// failing test
XCTAssertTrue( [setTwo count] == 0, @"This gets printed to the console" );
```

Back to your question:

> I want to let the test fail when the NSSet is empty. So the NSSet
>   should always hold data. When count is 0 --> break with an error.

You want to test some items have been added to `mySet`. There are two tests can use:

```
XCTAssertTrue( [mySet count] > 0, @"Should have at least one item" );
// or
XCTAssertFalse( [mySet count] == 0, @"mySet count is actually %d", [mySet count] );
```

Also:

> In my testcase the NSSet is empty. When i insert a if-statement and
>   ask for if (mySet.count == 0) it is true - so they are no elements in
>   the NSSet

If your set is empty, `XCTAssertTrue( mySet.count == 0, @"" )` passes because there no items in `mySet`.